# Composer two packages using the same package different version

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a Magento install, which uses the Monolog package. The satisfiable version is 1.16. But deployphp/deployer uses ^1.21  which are not compatible.

Is it impossible to use these two packages together? Or is there a fix? 
I do want to use the last versions of both packages if possible.

Comment: I don't find a composer package named php/deployer. Can you give us the correct package name?

Comment: sorry its here: deployphp/deployer

Comment: It looks like as long as you are in v4 of deployer you can use 1.21 of monolog

Comment: sorry magento uses 
        "monolog/monolog": "1.16.0",
and deployphp uses 1.21

Comment: I only see one solution, and that is using version 3.x-dev (or 3.3.0) of deployer/deployer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same package with different versions not possible, there may be chances of conflict

Comment: So its impossible to use both packages then?

Comment: if the versions has a same specification

Comment: if there is any update in php deployer..then it must support the latest version of monolog

Comment: I guess magento then, I mixed up the versions before. Magento uses the lowest one at the moment

Comment: u only have to do update magento, which supports 1.22 Or use old version of deployer